# Is it possible that SMTP email is working in project except one place?

Tags: laravel, email

In one project total four places I called sendemail function, In three places it is working but in one place it is not working.
I am using laravel5.3.. Please share if any clue

Comment: I am using laravel send email method with SMTP

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your current question is not clear and will be closed if you don't provide further info. Please post the code of the part that is not working.

Comment: I am using Mail::Send function of laravel to send an email. In three places this function works & email send properly, Only one place exist from where email is not send. I am using same function in every places.